# Protractor doesn't detect pop up dialog (md-dialog-content)

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation, protractor

```
it("Checking for file uploaded pop up window",function(){
    expect(element(by.css('md-dialog-content')).isPresent()).toBe(true); //Check the upload success window

    var h2 = element(by.css('md-dialog-content > h2')).getText(); //Get h2 of the pop up

    expect(h2).toEqual("Attention"); //h2 is equal to attention

    var h2Content = element(by.css('md-dialog-content > p')).getText(); //get h2 content

    expect(h2Content).toEqual("File: "+"repair_anonymized_1000sample.json"+" uploaded"); //content h2 is equal to ...

    element(by.css('.md-actions > button')).click(); //Click on the close button

    expect(element(by.css('md-dialog-content')).isPresent()).toBe(false); //THe dialog box will not exist

});
```

What I am trying to do is to check the Pop up dialog of 'md-dialog-content' element. I am checking it's h2 and p element inside it.

But protractor gave me an error saying that they are expecting the first expect to be 'false' instead of true. Which means that they did not detect md-dialog-content which is clearly there.

Yes the previous 'it' tests have gone through all the necessary steps to generate this dialog box to pop up.

The previous steps of my test specs (I am using ng-file-upload) :

```
it("Upload files",function(){

    var fileToUpload = "/home/vagrant/Desktop/repair_anonymized_1000sample.json";

    var absolutePath = path.resolve(fileToUpload);

    browser.executeAsyncScript(function(callback){ //Fire Fox needs this code to display the hidden input element or it will give error of element not visible

        document.querySelectorAll('input[type="file"]')[0]

        .style.visibility= 'visible';

        callback();

    });

    var input = element(by.css('input[type="file"]'));

    input.sendKeys(absolutePath);   

    browser.sleep(2000); //wait for the alert to appear

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to *wait for the popup dialog to [become present](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.presenceOf)*:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions,
    dialog = element(by.css('md-dialog-content'));  // or just $('md-dialog-content')

browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(dialog), 5000);
```

If you are getting the Timeout Exception, this means that the element is either not there, or your locator is incorrect, or may be the element is inside an iframe.

Comment: The element is there. The locater is also correct. And the element is not inside iframe. The element is generated so it is placed at the bottom of the html along with my ng-file-upload stuff. Does that have to do with the problem?

Comment: @geoffreykoh should not be a problem. Do you think you can make a reproducible example so I can see the problem too? Thanks.